# Current Menu Item styling in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on a site here: http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/

I want the current menu item in the main nav to be white instead of gray. In this case, if you are on the home page the home link in the nav will be white.

Whatever I try it remains gray.

```css
    .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main div.menu > ul > li > a,


    .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li > a {


      color: #ccc;


      text-transform: uppercase;


    }


    .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main div.menu > ul > li > a:hover,


    .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li > a:hover {


      color: #ccc;


      text-transform: uppercase;


      text-decoration: underline;


    }


    .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main div.menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a,


    .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li.current_page_item > a {


      color: #fff;


    }
```

```html
<div class="standard-menu-container  menu-skin-main reveal-from-top">

  <a href="#" class="menu-bar menu-skin-main hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <span class="ham"></span>
  </a>


  <nav>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu-main-nav-1">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-631 current_page_item menu-item-645"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-646"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/our-work/">Our Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-647"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/our-services/">Our Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-648"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/our-team/">Our Team</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Other Nav links -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

.main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main div.menu > ul > li > a, .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li > a { color: #ccc; text-transform: uppercase; } .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu
.standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main div.menu > ul > li > a:hover, .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li > a:hover { color: #ccc; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration:underline; } .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu
.standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main div.menu > ul > li.current_page_item > a, .main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li.current_page_item > a { color: #fff; }


<div class="standard-menu-container  menu-skin-main reveal-from-top">

  <a href="#" class="menu-bar menu-skin-main hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <span class="ham"></span>
  </a>


  <nav>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu-main-nav-1">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-631 current_page_item menu-item-645"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-646"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/our-work/">Our Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-647"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/our-services/">Our Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-648"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/our-team/">Our Team</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Other Nav links -->
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.current-menu-item.page_item.page-item-631.current_page_item.menu-item-645 a{
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
}
```

The problem is css specificity, if you check google chrome there are a lot of identifiers, so you need to build points, or as a last option, use `!important`